# Transform big number into scientific format

Tags: formatting, calculations

I want to convert my big integer number into a shorter form; for example

```
\convert{123456789} = 1.23 x 10^9
```

Is there any package which allows me to do so?

Comment: How big is the big integer: 14 or fewer digits, or could it have a potentially arbitrary number of digits? After conversion to "scientific" format, how many digits should be retained?

Comment: Around 20+ digits is the size of the integers. I would like to make the number of retained digit configurable, but if not then 2 3 should be ok. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The PGF math engine can do it.

In addition, the `pgfplotstable` package is quite powerful when it comes to rounding, formatting, and perhaps even postprocessing/generating numerical content.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathprintnumber{123456789123456789123456789}

\pgfplotstabletypeset{
A B
1 123456789123456789123456789
2 9876543219876545432198765432222
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Based on the comment on my answer, does this work with a `pgfplotstable` release from say 2009?

Comment: @JosephWright `\pgfmathprintnumber` works this way since its first release; `pgfplotstable` as well. If the precise date matters, I would need to take a closer look (I assume this is unnecessary for now). Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 13):

Not the core aim of the package, but `siunitx` does have lots of number-processing code built in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

$\num{123456789} =
  \num[round-precision = 3, round-mode = figures, scientific-notation = true]
    {123456789}$.

\end{document}
```

Note  at present *some* of the internals of `siunitx` are limited to 'TeX-sized' numbers, but I am currently working on the next major release and this is one of the things to deal with. Fix for the present:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,l3bigint}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn
  \__siunitx_number_process_scientific_aux_ii:nnn #1#2#3 {
  \bigint_compare:nNnTF {#1} > { 9 }
    { \__siunitx_number_process_scientific_large:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
    {
      \bigint_compare:nNnTF {#1} > { 0 }
        {
          \bool_if:NTF \l__siunitx_process_engineering_bool
            { \__siunitx_number_process_scientific_engineering:nnn }
            { \__siunitx_number_process_scientific_store:nnn }
               {#1} {#2} {#3}
        }
        {
          \__siunitx_number_process_scientific_small:wn
            #2 \q_stop {#3}
        }
    }
}
\cs_set_protected:Npn
  \__siunitx_number_process_scientific_large:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl
      { \bigint_div_truncate:nn {#1} { 10 } }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl
      { \bigint_mul:nn { \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl } { 10 } }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl
      { \bigint_sub:nn {#1} { \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl } }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl
      {
        { \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl } { \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl #2 }
        { #3 + 1 }
      }
  \exp_after:wN \__siunitx_number_process_scientific_aux_ii:nnn
    \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$\num{1234567890123456789} =
  \num[round-precision = 3, round-mode = figures, scientific-notation = true]
    {1234567890123456789}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Loi.Luu I'm meant to be fixing one or two bugs to do with 'large' integers. However, I'm never really sure where these come up 'in the wild' in a place where rounding/truncation is legitimate.

Comment: Thanks, I got this `! Package xkeyval Error: round-precision undefined in families `key'.` when inserted  `$\num[round-precision=3,round-mode=figures, scientific-notation = true]{933952}$` as a cell of a table. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Loi.Luu Using version 1 of `siunitx` rather than version 2: is you have an older TeX set up then the choice of packages will be somewhat more limited

Comment: Is the `l3bigint` package part of the TeXLive (or MikTeX) distribution?

Comment: @Mico Part of `l3trial`, so to be fair you would have to grab that from the LaTeX3 master repo or [GitHub](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror). As I've tried to indicate, I need to think about some issues before updating the `siunitx` code in this area (and others). One thing I need to do is see if the team feel that 'big integers' are worth supporting.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. Incidentally, as I point out in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164403/5001), there's a quick fix available right now for people if they're willing to use LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @JosephWright will `siunitx` support breaking across lines?

Comment: @jfbu Possibly: I need to think about the technical issues and knock-on effect on existing use cases.

Comment: @JosephWright regarding `l3bigint` how would one access its basic arithmetic macros? in other words how should I define `\bnumexprAdd`, `\bnumexprSub`, `\bnumexprMul`, `\bnumexprDiv` in my package [bnumexpr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bnumexpr) for the expressions to be evaluated using `l3bigint`?

Comment: @jfbu `\bigint_add:nn` and so on, at present.

Comment: @JosephWright silly me, before I attempt installing `l3bigint` one more silly question: these are expandable macros right?

Comment: @jfbu Of course: it's much the same as your code or Heiko's in that respect (I've not read the implementation carefully so that may be different).

Comment: @JosephWright I feel truly stupid for this series of questions. Don't know why I made such a big fuss about putting a `l3bigint.sty` file in my repertory and `\let\bnumexprDiv\bigint_div_round:nn` etc... it just works. I will add `l3bigint` option to `bnumexpr`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution that employs LuaLaTeX. There's a TeX-side macro called `\tosci` and a Lua-side function called `tosci`. The number of digits shown can be selected by modifying the first argument of the function `string.format` used by `tosci`.

The output of `\tosci` can be used by itself if you like the `1.234e+09` look. To get the `1.234 x 10^9` look, there's another TeX-side macro called `\convert`, which nests the `\tosci` macro inside the `\num` macro of the [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package. Note: I use the name `\convert` because that's the name you gave in your posting; you may want to come up with a more descriptive name.

Aside: A benefit of using `\convert` is that one needn't worry about the number being too big -- i.e., having too many digits -- for the current version of `siunitx`'s `\num` macro to handle on its own.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment and '\luastring' macro
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\num' macro

% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode} 
   function tosci ( n ) 
      return ( string.format ( "%.3e", n ) ) -- show 3 digits after the decimal
   end
\end{luacode}

% TeX-side code
\newcommand{\tosci}[1]{%
    \directlua{tex.sprint ( tosci ( \luastring{#1} ) ) }}
\newcommand{\convert}[1]{\num{\tosci{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\tosci{123456789012}, \tosci{1234123412341234}

\convert{456745674567456745674}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The macro as you requested using again `pgfmath`

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd ,precision=2,sci generic={exponent={\times 10^{#1}}}}
\newcommand\convert[1]{\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}

\begin{document}

\convert{123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using in combination:

> 1. the `\xintFloat [P]` macro of [xintfrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint), with `P` the arbitrary asked for
>      precision, its output will be of the form `<non zero digit>.<digit>...<digit>e<integer exponent>`, with a total number of `P` digits in the significand,
> 2. and the `\numprint` macro of package [numprint](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) which will transform such a thing into a customizable form, by default something like `x.y \times 10^{exponent}`, grouping digits by three, possibly with  a separator.

The `\xintFloat` macro being expandable, one just need to nest the macro calls:

```
\numprint {\xintFloat [7]{123456789012345678901234567890}}
\numprint {\xintFloat [13]{123456789012345678901234567890}}
```

> [image: float print]

The input to `\xintFloat` is not limited to be a big integer: it may be itself a scientific number such as `6.02e23`, or a decimal number `2627.72827` without scientific exponent, or even a fraction whose numerator and denominator are each of the previous types or just big integers. For example `1234567890/9876543210`: (the default precision is with `16` digits, the last one is rounded).

```
\numprint {\xintFloat {1234567890/9876543210}}
```

> [image: float print 2]

source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xintfrac}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\begin{document}

text mode (ttfamily):
\texttt{\numprint {\xintFloat [7]{123456789012345678901234567890}}} and
\texttt{\numprint {\xintFloat [13]{123456789012345678901234567890}}}

math mode:
$\numprint {\xintFloat [7]{123456789012345678901234567890}}$ and
$\numprint {\xintFloat [13]{123456789012345678901234567890}}$

\numprint {\xintFloat {1234567890/9876543210}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Loi.Luu I mentioned only `numprint` and its macro `\numprint`, but the `\num` of `siunitx` will work too (and `\xintFloat` will become unnecessary if `siunitx` adds support for big numbers to its rounding code).